# find in mongodb document with custom poco object as id

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB.Bson 2.2.3 driver,

I have a document with POCO as a document ID. I wanted to ask what is a good way of querying for such document by Id? I tried to do:

```
FilterDefinition filter = builder.Eq("id.field1", poco.Field1) & builder.Eq("id.field2", poco.Field2));
var result = await DbCollection().FindAsync(filter);
```

But it doesn't seem to find anything. I can't find good examples.

Document definition is like:

```
class Document 
{
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(PocoIdGenerator))]
        public Poco Id { get; set; }
}
```

And Poco definition is like:

```
class Poco 
{
        public String Field1 { get; set; }
        public String Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:
example document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "field1": "something",
        "field2": "something2"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the document containing "id"? When I access fields on my mongodatabase it would be `builder.Eq("containerDocumentName.id", poco.Field1)`. Unless the collection-you-are-querying-against's documents themselves have "id" as a top level field, then you just do `builder.Eq("id", poco.Field1)`.

Comment: Hi, so DbCollection() is returning IMongoCollection<Document> object, so I shouldn't have to specify collection in a query. Additionally id is not equal to single string, it's an json object, so the second proposition won't work neither, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my first error was that I should use "_id":

```
FilterDefinition filter = builder.Eq("_id.field1", poco.Field1) & builder.Eq("_id.field2", poco.Field2));
```

But I can achieve similar thing more elegant using lambdas:

```
FilterDefinition<Document> filter = builder.Eq(ob => ob.Id, sess);
```